# Delphi TJvHidDeviceController : device cannot be opened

Tags: delphi, hid

When I put an **TJvHidDeviceController** ( *HIDKomponent from soft-gems.net* ) component on my form and run the application I get an error message : **device cannot be opened**

I am Using Delphi XE2 and Windows 7.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: JvHidControllerClass.pas in that package is dated 2007. Use the component from JEDI itself instead.

Comment: thanks @SertacAkyuz , which package?

Comment: @Mohammad - It's in "JVCL System Components Runtime Package" JvSystemD#R.dpk. You're welcome.